# jQuery Dynamic Order Form

Tags: jquery, html

I am building an order form using HTML and jQuery and it is complete, but I would like to know if there is a better way to build it or anything wrong with the way I have done it.  In case you need to know this will be posted to an "classic asp" page.  Here is my page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>SKU</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RemoveRow(htmlelement){

            $(htmlelement).parent().parent().remove();

        }
        function AddRow(){

            //Create a new row
            var NewRow = $("#clonerow").clone(true).attr("id","newrow");        

            //Modify the row text fields with new names
            $.each($(NewRow).find("input[name^='Order']"), function (k,v) {
                $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name").replace("Stub",$("#CurrentNum").val()));
                $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id").replace("Stub",$("#CurrentNum").val()));
            })

            $(NewRow).removeAttr("id");

            //Update the row number
            $("#CurrentNum").val(parseInt($("#CurrentNum").val()) + 1);

            //append the new row
            $(NewRow).insertBefore("#buttonrow");

        }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #clonerow {
            display:none;
        }

        #order thead td {
            background:silver;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #order input[type="text"] {
            width:95%;
        }

        #order img {
            border-style: none;
        }

        #order a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: gray">
    <input name="SONum" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="CurrentNum" id="CurrentNum" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <div id="orderdiv" style="width:930px;">
        <table id="order" cellpadding="0" style="width:930px;">
            <thead>
                <td>SKU</td>
                <td>Style#</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Pattern</td>
                <td>Size</td>
                <td>Color</td>
                <td>Qty</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </thead>
            <tr id="clonerow">
                <td><input id ="OrderSKUStub" name="OrderSKUStub" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderStyleNumStub" name="OrderStyleNumStub" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderDescriptionStub" name="OrderDescriptionStub" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderPatternStub" name="OrderPatternStub" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderSizeStub" name="OrderSizeStub" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderColorStub" name="OrderColorStub" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderQtyStub" name="OrderQtyStub" type="text" /></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="RemoveRow(this);" name="anchor"><img alt="delete" src="001_05.gif" name="delete"/></a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input id ="OrderSKU" name="OrderSKU" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderStyleNum" name="OrderStyleNum" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderDescription" name="OrderDescription" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderPattern" name="OrderPattern" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderSize" name="OrderSize" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderColor" name="OrderColor" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input id="OrderQty" name="OrderQty" type="text" /></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="RemoveRow(this);" name="anchor"><img alt="delete" src="001_05.gif" name="delete"/></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="buttonrow">
                <td colspan="8"><input name="AddRowButton" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow();" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Wade

**Edit:**  I forgot to add that I am interested in how best to set the width of the columns.  I tried setting different element's widths (using css), but it never seemed to work correctly.  I want the table to remain 930px wide.

Comment: I would sugest using <script id="clonerow_template" defer type="text/html"> for templates, it hides its content form jQuery
.
also for counter storage use $('clonerow_template').data('counter')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few things:

- Remove your `onClick` bindings in the html, so it becomes `a.btn-remove`.
- Ideally you'd want your `tr#clonerow` as an html partial. I'd suggest looking into things like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) to never repeat your UI markup.
- Create a jquery plugin like `$.fn.formGrid` or `function formGrid(){}; formGrid.prototype.addRow = function(){}; formGrid.prototype.removeRow(){};` that makes your form logic more modular, encapsulated (your functions are currently polluting the global scope), and reusable. Then change `tr#buttonrow` to `tr.buttonrow`. I would suggest storing a context jQuery object like `$formGrid` as a property in the module object, so you can have multiple instances of this dynamic order form, if desired.

Comment: Not sure how I would do item 1, I am rather new to the Javascript realm.  I am using classic asp so not sure yet how I would use it, but Mustache would be a great help.

Comment: The gist of it is: module.$context.find('tr a').click(function(evt){evt.preventDefault(); module.removeRow($(this).closest('tr')); }); -- that makes it seem a bit complicated, but it's only because I'm still making it work with the removeRow method.